# CakePHP routing without trailing path info

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I have a simple CakePHP which I want to use without URL rewriting. The site which works fine locally but not on my hosting server. My sysadmin has advised me that:

> The PHP wrapper doesn't accept trailing path-info like `script.php/additional/path/info`

CakePHP seems to expect this by default. How do I get around this limitation? I guess I need to pass the path information via the query string instead, so instead of URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller/action
```

I probably will need something like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?path=controller/action
```

I'm sure this should be doable by changing the routing scheme somehow, but how? I have tried reading the docs, and digging into the framework source code is kind of daunting... Thanks!

Comment: How is it easier to not use `mod_rewrite` when this requires you to find crude workarounds for your weird environment?

Comment: What I mean is that the `mod_rewrite` itself works; I can omit the `index.php` and have exactly the same issue. But I turned it off to help in debugging the issue.

Comment: What exactly is the issue then ("_doesn't work_" isn't very informative)? `mod_rewrite` and trailing path info are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I know they are different. The issue is that the hosting environment does not support trailing path info, so I want to pass the path information (`controller/action` etc) via the query string instead. I guess this will require some changes to the routing scheme but don't know if this is easily doable.

Comment: Well, you said that you are facing the exactly same issue when using `mod_rewrite`, but `mod_rewrite` works differently than passing trailing path info, so I would be surprised if this would really be the same problem, and that's why I'm asking for a description of the actual problem. Anyways, using query strings would require modifying the core, that's a no-go, so I would suggest that you forget about that and switch to a different host in case yours cannot even provide basic `mod_rewrite` functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ndm. The truth is that I've had a bunch of problems with this host and tried to simplify things when asking the question here, although you're right that it's not exactly the same problem in either case. It turns out my problem was a combination of needing `RewriteBase` in my `.htaccess` files and having some incorrect file permissions. The original question is still of interest however (about using the query string). I have amended the question slightly, perhaps you would like to post your reply as an answer which I can accept. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your simple solution is how to remove trailing slash from URL using .htaccess. This may be done by the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This should be placed in the .htaccess file where your application's index.php.